# New lines/tabulators turn into spaces in generated document

Tags: python, python-docx

I have problem with `\n` and `\t` tags. When I am opening a generated `.docx` in *OpenOffice* everything looks fine, but when I open the same document in *Microsoft Word* I just get the last two tabulators in section `"Surname"` and spaces instead of newlines/tabulators in other sections. What is wrong?

```
p = document.add_paragraph('Simple paragraph')
p.add_run('Name:\t\t' + name).bold = True
p.add_run('\n\nSurname:\t\t' + surname)
```

Comment: In Windows it's '\r\n' that's maybe the problem?

Comment: The formatting of text editors is often very different. Some you have control over (most coding based text editors allow you to set tabs as a bunch of spaces or an actual tab) and others you don't/it might be complex to change the default behavior. It's an arbitrary thing and it's generally just something you have to code around.

Comment: I tried \r\n but this new line is not even a space now. I am using Linux (coding) and Windows for opening a documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Word, what we often think of as a line feed translates to a paragraph object. If you want empty paragraphs in your document you will need to insert them explicitly.

First of all though, you should ask whether you're using paragraphs for formatting, a common casual practice for Word users but one you might want to deal with differently, in particular by using the space-before and/or space-after properties of a paragraph. In HTML this would correspond roughly to padding-top and padding-bottom.

In this case, if you just want the line feeds, consider using paragraphs like so:

```
document.add_paragraph('Simple paragraph')
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run('Name:\t\t').bold = True
p.add_run(name)
document.add_paragraph()
p = document.add_paragraph()
p.add_run('Surname:\t\t').bold = True
p.add_run(surname)
```

Comment: This workaround code gave me "dirty" new line but tabulators are still invisible.

Comment: It is funny but this tabulators work fine: p.add_run('\n\nSurname:\t\t' + surname)

Comment: k, turns out Word has a special XML element for a tab character that python-docx doesn't support yet. If you'll add a feature request to the project issue tracker on Github I'll see about adding it in. https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues?state=open

Comment: Hmm, still, this should work. It seems to be working on my side. Let me try to reproduce it.

Comment: Ah, ok, I got it. If the tab characters are *trailing* (or line feed characters *leading*), python-docx inserts an `xml:space="preserve"` attribute in the text element. If the tabs are embedded and there is no leading whitespace, it doesn't. For whatever reason,  Word translates the embedded tabs to spaces if there's no preserve element. The workaround would be to put the field name (e.g. 'Surname:\t\t') into one run and the actual surname value into another. I've updated the code example above.

Comment: Tabulators are OK now, unfortunately this solution doesn't work for \n.